# mysql adding a new column to label the time-series data points for each id

Tags: mysql, time-series

I got time-series data storing in a table as follows.

```
   id,       timestamp,             value
   d1   2000-01-01 00:00:00          1
   d1   2000-01-01 01:00:00          2
   d1   2000-01-01 02:00:00          3
   d1   2000-01-01 03:00:00          4
   d1   2000-01-01 04:00:00          5
...
   d2   2000-01-01 00:00:00          25
   d2   2000-01-01 01:00:00          26
   d2   2000-01-01 02:00:00          27
   d2   2000-01-01 03:00:00          28
   d2   2000-01-01 04:00:00          29
   d2   2000-01-01 05:00:00          30
...
   d3   2000-01-01 00:00:00          49
   d3   2000-01-01 01:00:00          50
   d3   2000-01-01 02:00:00          51
   d3   2000-01-01 03:00:00          52
   d3   2000-01-01 04:00:00          53
```

What I need to do is to add another column to the table as follows.
The purpose is to label the number of data points for each id for further process.

```
  id,       timestamp,             value,     counter
   d1   2000-01-01 00:00:00          1           1 
   d1   2000-01-01 01:00:00          2           2
   d1   2000-01-01 02:00:00          3           3 
   d1   2000-01-01 03:00:00          4           4
   d1   2000-01-01 04:00:00          5           5
...
   d2   2000-01-01 00:00:00          25          1
   d2   2000-01-01 00:00:00          26          2
   d2   2000-01-01 01:00:00          27          3
   d2   2000-01-01 02:00:00          28          4 
   d2   2000-01-01 03:00:00          29          5
   d2   2000-01-01 04:00:00          30          6
...
   d3   2000-01-01 00:00:00          49          1
   d3   2000-01-01 01:00:00          50          2
   d3   2000-01-01 02:00:00          51          3
   d3   2000-01-01 03:00:00          52          4
   d3   2000-01-01 04:00:00          53          5
```

How to realise it using mysql command?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
yt.*
, IF(@prev=id, @counter:=@counter + 1, @counter:=1) as counter
, @prev:=id
FROM
yourTable yt
, (SELECT @counter:=0, @prev:=NULL) vars
order by id, `timestamp`
```

See it live [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a96ad/3/0).

Comment: @user2258149 You're welcome. The usual way to say thank you here is to accept and/or upvote an answer :)

Comment: I did, however it requires 15 reputation points to upvote the answer.

Comment: Could you explain briefly the latter part of the command? (SELECT counter:=0, prev:=NULL) vars

Comment: This is just to initialize the variables on the fly inside the statement. Same would be to do `SET @counter:=0; SET @prev:=NULL; SELECT...FROM yourTable yt ORDER BY id, timestamp`.